# #Kotlin Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:debugRuntimeClasspath'

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, gradle-kotlin-dsl, kotlin-android-extensions

I searched a lot, but I don't have a solution for this error:

```
Caused by: org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.DefaultLenientConfiguration$ArtifactResolveException: Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:debugRuntimeClasspath'.
```

[image: Error]

build.gradle(Module):
[image: gradle module]

build.gradle(Project):
[image: gradle project]

Do you have a solution for this?

Comment: In Build Output tab -> Click on writeDebugSigningConfigVersions line & check which library is not compiled.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in Build Gradle (Module), Remove kotlin-android-extensions on line 41 because kotlin-android-extensions is already added above. I had the same problem with room and coroutines now and this method worked